# how do I omit parent less nodes in an hierarchical (connect by) oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a table named CATEGORY with the columns

- CATEGORY_NAME
- CATEGORY_PARENT_NAME
- ACTIVE

And this query

```
SELECT *
FROM CATEGORY
WHERE ACTIVE = 'TRUE'
START WITH CATEGORY_PARENT_NAME IS NULL   
CONNECT BY CATEGORY_PARENT_NAME = PRIOR CATEGORY_NAME   
ORDER SIBLINGS BY MENU_INDEX
```

I'm trying to get only the active child nodes whose the root parents are active, but oracle also returns the active child nodes of the inactive roots, even through their parents were filtered in the where clause. I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you are filtering only the child nodes in your where clause. Perhaps you can try this to filter the parent nodes. `START WITH CATEGORY_PARENT_NAME IS NULL AND  ACTIVE = 'TRUE'`.

Comment: @Ramblin'Man that worked for me. Can you put that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify your START BY clause to include `ACTIVE = TRUE`, so that only those roots which are active will be considered.

WHERE clause will be applied later, so that you can filter out only the ACTIVE child nodes.

```
 select *
   from category
  where active = 'TRUE'
  start with category_parent_name is null
    and active = 'TRUE' 
connect by category_parent_name = prior category_name   
  order siblings by menu_index;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query (see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9bcff/2)) will give you all the *active* nodes whose *root* is active:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT c.*,
    PRIOR c.ACTIVE AS PARENT_ACTIVE,
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT(c.CATEGORY_NAME) AS CATEGORY_ROOT_NAME,
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT(c.ACTIVE) AS ROOT_ACTIVE
  FROM CATEGORY c
  WHERE c.ACTIVE = 'TRUE'
  START WITH c.CATEGORY_PARENT_NAME IS NULL   
  CONNECT BY c.CATEGORY_PARENT_NAME = PRIOR c.CATEGORY_NAME   
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY c.MENU_INDEX
) a
WHERE a.ROOT_ACTIVE = 'TRUE'
```

To further filter your results to only include active nodes whose parent, grandparent, and all of the ancestor nodes up to the hierarchy root are active (see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9bcff/4)):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT c.*,
    PRIOR c.ACTIVE AS PARENT_ACTIVE,
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT(c.CATEGORY_NAME) AS CATEGORY_ROOT_NAME,
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT(c.ACTIVE) AS ROOT_ACTIVE,
    SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(c.ACTIVE, '/') AS ACTIVE_PATH
  FROM CATEGORY c
  WHERE c.ACTIVE = 'TRUE'
  START WITH c.CATEGORY_PARENT_NAME IS NULL   
  CONNECT BY c.CATEGORY_PARENT_NAME = PRIOR c.CATEGORY_NAME   
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY c.MENU_INDEX
) a
WHERE a.ROOT_ACTIVE = 'TRUE'
  AND a.ACTIVE_PATH NOT LIKE '%FALSE%'
```

**Tips**

- Use the [`CONNECT_BY_ROOT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/operators004.htm) operator to obtain a column value from the root node.
- Use the [`PRIOR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/operators004.htm) operator to obtain a column value from the parent node (just watch for `NULL`s when you are on the root node)
- Use the [`SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions183.htm) function to obtain a column's values all the way up to the root node.